# Use the Django Rest Framework with tables not defined in your models.py

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I finished a [tutorial with the Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/) and I am super excited with this approach of developing, meaning to have separated the front end with the back end and have those two communicate with a REST API.

So at this point I am trying to wrap my head around the DRF idea and here I am stuck with the following question: With the Django Rest API you can actually fetch data (e.g. in JSON format) from your django models. Later in your frontend, you can get these data via an AJAX request (using jquery or react or angular) and then you display them..

But all these data they come from the tables which are also defined as Django models. What if I need to get the data from a database (tables) which is not defined in the models.py? Does the DRF works in these cases? What approach would I follow?

Comment: Why wouldn't you define the table as a model? Django is quite capable of taking an existing database and creating models from it.

Comment: What database are you using for those tables? If for some reason you don't want django to manage your database, you can still create the appropiate models and use `managed=False`, see docs here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/#managed

Comment: @GabrielMuj I am using Postgres. For example in one project I have two databases. The first one has all the tables defined also in the django models.py files (for each app) and the second one has tables with data which are used for mapping purposes (these tables are created by users; via uploading).

Comment: But its the data in those tables that I need to retrieve in json format and map them (or display them) later

Comment: You still can use django rest framework, but you cannot use some of the features like generic views or viesets that needs a queryset to work. For example I used normal class based views to get data from a non relational database, there was some extra work to do (eg. pagination) so be prepared to add functionality that works out of the box with generic views.

Comment: @GabrielMuj So in your view you used psycopg2 to connect to the postgres and fetch the data? (or any equivalent library depending on your database)

Comment: Exactly, I used a specific client to fetch data, then I just create a Response object (from drf) and return it in the view. drf will handle the appropiate conversion to json/xml (depending in your default rendering class). I created some utility functions to fetch data from db, you can do the same, or even a class that does your queries in order to reuse functionality in other views and have a clear design.